# parsing string with spaces in Awk

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I have a file with the following values:

```
 ID1 RID1 2 rid1 part2
 ID1 RID2 1 rid2 part1
 ID1 RID2 2 rid2 part2
 ID2 RID3 1 rid3 part1
 ID2 RID3 2 rid3 part2
 ID2 RID4 1 rid4 part1
```

ID RID Offset Text. ID, RID, Offset and Text are tab delimited. The text can be multiple words with spaces in between.

I am trying to concatenate them based on RID and ascending offset.

Essentially the desired output is

```
ID2     RID3    rid3 part1rid3 part2
ID2     RID4    rid4 part1
ID1     RID1    rid1 part1rid1 part2
ID1     RID2    rid2 part1rid2 part2
```

I am trying to do this with awk. Here is my awk 1 liner:

```
cat example.txt| awk '{line=""; line = line $4; table[$1"\t"$2]=table[$1"\t"$2] line;} END {for (key in table) print key"\t"table[key];}'
```

For some reason, awk is not able to parse all the words in $4, i.e, it is just picking the 1st word and outputting:

```
ID2     RID3    rid3rid3
ID2     RID4    rid4
ID1     RID1    rid1rid1
ID1     RID2    rid2rid2
```

How do I parse all the words in $4 and not just the 1st word?

Comment: Have you tried `awk -F "\t"` to set the field separator to tab rather than any combination of spaces and tabs as is the default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest something like :

```
awk -F " " '{key=$1" "$2; value=$4" "$5; if(! key in t){t[key]=value} else {t[key]=t[key]""value}} END {for (key in t){print key" "t[key]}}' file|sort -rt' ' -k1
```

Regards,
Idriss

Answer (score 0):

Start with this updated version of your own script:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=SUBSEP="\t"} {table[$1,$2]=table[$1,$2] $4} END{for (key in table) print key, table[key]}' example.txt
```

Let us know if that doesn't do what you want and you need help figuring out how to fix it.

Comment: ID2 RID3 1 rid3 part1   
This doesn't exactly output what I need: Here's what its outputting ID1 RID2 1 rid2 part1   
ID2 RID4 1 rid4 part1   
ID1 RID1 1 rid1 part1   
ID2 RID3 2 rid3 part2   
ID1 RID2 2 rid2 part2   
ID1 RID1 2 rid1 part2